# Read CSV File in Spark and Write it to Cassandra

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I am trying to read a CVS File with Spark and then save it to Cassandra. Saving to Cassandra is working, when I'm using trivial values.

I have a file with the following values:

`id,name,tag1|tag2|tag3`

I want to store it in a cassandra table:

`id bigint, name varchar, tags set`

I defined a case class for this:

`case class Item(id:Integer,name:String,tag:Set[String])`

Then I use this expression for getting the RDD out of the CVS file

`val items = sc.textFile("items.csv").map(l => l.split(",") match {case Array (a,b,c) => Item(Integer.parseInt(a),b,c.split("\\|").toSet)})`

When I now call `collect` or `saveToCassandra` on items (which starts the processing) I get the following error:

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 29.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 29.0 (TID 38, localhost): scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@6030bbe6 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:33)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: What's case class Item(id:Integer,name:String,tag[String]) ? Is tag a Set[String] ?

Comment: yes, its a Set[String]. I changed it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the issue is that splitting on some inputs is generating an array that has less or more than the 3 elements used in the match.

But the `partialFuntion` used to do the match can be used to filter on the elements that *do* fit the match criteria. `rdd.collect{partialFunction}` is exactly meant for that:

```
val data = sc.textFile("items.csv")
val arrayData = data.map(l => l.split(","))
val items = arrayData.collect{case Array (a,b,c) => Item(Integer.parseInt(a),b,c.split("\\|").toSet)})
 items.saveToCassandra(...)
```

- Note1: you should also protect against dirty values. e.g. parseInt on a value that's not an int number,...)
- Note2: `rdd.collect{partialFunc}` (filters/map data using a partial function) should not be confused with `rdd.collect` (get back data to the driver))

Comment: you both are right, the data format was incorrect. i marked this as accepted answer as it provides a nice workaround when you don't rely on the whole data.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get that match error if your input *isn't* an array of 3 entries e.g.

```
String("a,b").split(",") match {
   case Array(a,b,c) => ....
}
```

so I suspect this is some input data issue, and you need to cater for it in your `match`.

Answer (score 1):

I use below to save my CSV file "|" seperated to cassandra DB.
Hope this will help

```
package com
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object CsvLoad {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val log = LogManager.getRootLogger

    log.info("**********JAR EXECUTION STARTED**********")
    val properties: Properties = new Properties
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(args(0)))

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName(getClass.getName)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", properties.getProperty("CASSANDRA_HOST"))
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", properties.getProperty("CASSANDRA_PORT"))
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", properties.getProperty("CASSANDRA_USERNAME"))
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "Jcloud@1357")
      .set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes", "32")
      .set("spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level", "ONE")
      .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb","67108864")
      .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key", "none")

     val sc=new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val spark = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val data = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema", "true").
      load("D:\\data.csv")

    val output = data.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("table" -> "mytable", "keyspace" -> "test", "cluster" -> "Test Cluster"))
    output.save()
  }

}
```